# Getting Error "System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001"

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits

i am suddenly getting the following error in apex trigger :

"System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001"

Here is my apex trigger code :

```
trigger SetAmountfromOTTtoSFDC on Opportunity (Before Insert, Before Update) {

Map <string, Id> AccountTextIdMap = new Map<String,Id>();
Map <string, Id> ContactTextIdMap = new Map<String,Id>();

if(Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUpdate){
    List<Account> AccList = [select Id, Name, AccountId__c from Account];
    for(Account ac : AccList){
        AccountTextIdMap.put(ac.AccountID__c, ac.id);
    }
    List<Contact> ConList = [select Id, Contact_ID__c from Contact];
    for(Contact con : ConList){
        ContactTextIdMap.put(con.Contact_ID__c, con.id);
    }

    for(Opportunity op : Trigger.New){

        if(op.AdrAccountSearchKey__c != Null && op.AccountId == Null){
            op.AccountId = AccountTextIdMap.get(op.AdrAccountSearchKey__c);
        }

        if(op.AdrContactSearchKey__c != Null && op.Contact__c == Null){
            op.Contact__c = ContactTextIdMap.get(op.AdrContactSearchKey__c);
        }
     }
}
```

I am using this trigger to set up the records which all are coming from other system using synchronization

i think Batch is very useful to this case but i am not sure how to do it, can somebody help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 List<Account> AccList = [select Id, Name, AccountId__c from Account];
 List<Contact> ConList = [select Id, Contact_ID__c from Contact];
```

Might chances that these query are causing this issue. So you can update here to something like

```
Set<Id> accIdset = new Set<ID>();
Set<Id> conIdset = new Set<ID>();
for(Opportunity op : Trigger.New){
     if(op.AdrAccountSearchKey__c != null)
          accIdset.add(op.AdrAccountSearchKey__c);

      if(op.AdrContactSearchKey__c != null)
          conIdset.add(op.AdrContactSearchKey__c);
}
```

and then in your query update them and use this set

```
List<Account> AccList = [select Id, Name, AccountId__c from Account WHERE AccountId__c  IN: accIdset];

List<Contact> ConList = [select Id, Contact_ID__c from Contact WHERE Contact_ID__c IN: conIdset];
```

This will reduce your number of records still with very large data you might hit the limit.

Comment: Thanks Tushar !! Can we use Batch apex if Limit is hit ?

Comment: @Nihar Sure you can but it depends on complete requirement because you will not get real time update. Also if it solve your problem then you can accept the answer.